# JProfiler - How to generate Memory_telemetry.csv in command line?

Tags: jprofiler

I would like to automatize a process that tests my application with JProfiler. My goal is to test some properties of the measure report in memory telemetry view.

Today, I am able to do the following:
(1) run, in command line, my application with jprofiler and generate jps file
(2) launch jprofilerGUI, import the jps and then export Memory_telemetry.csv
(3) run, in command line, my tool that check properties on Memory_telemetry.csv.

As you notice, step (2) is hand made. How to avoid it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

JProfiler has a command line utility `bin/jpexport` that can export all views. See the [documentation](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/export/export.html) for help on the arguments.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot

jpexport profile.jps "TelemetryHeap" profile_telemetry.cvs